# How to data bind from view to view model in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a question on how to bind from entry tag/view to view model using a class. I'm having a null value whenever I try to submit the data going to my view model class.

Here is the code for the view:

```
Entry Text="{Binding User.UserName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding User.Password, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
```

Here is the code for the view model(constructor part):

```
 public LoginPageViewModel(IApiService apiService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.apiService = apiService;
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
        LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(Login);
    }
```

In the view model, I have also a class for the username and password where it uses the model of User:

```
 private Users user;
    public Users User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { SetProperty(ref user, value); }
    }
```

Here is the model for the Users:

```
public class Users : BindableObject
{
    private string username;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }

    private string password;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; }
    }

}
```

Every time I tried to hit the submit button, I get the null value when I tried to debug my code.

```
private async void Login()
    {
        var test = User.UserName;

        bool success = await apiService.LoginAsync(User);
```

Thank you for your help on my Xamarin project.

Comment: when you create LoginViewModel, does it instantiate a new instance of User, or is it just null?

Comment: @Jason It is just null value at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of User at your viewmodel constructor.

```
public LoginPageViewModel(IApiService apiService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.apiService = apiService;
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
        LoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(Login);

        this.User = new Users();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you site an example for this.

Comment: Thank you @Jason and @Diego! Brilliant!